# UITableViewCell contentView frame move too much to the right in editing mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've a `UIImageView`, `UILabel`, `UIButton` in my custom `UITableViewCell`.
When I set editing mode to YES, the entire cell frame moves too much to the right.

Scrolling the table up and down seems to fix it.

But why it happens and how can I really fix it?

Comment: "Too much" compared to what? Compared to nothing, or to the indent you expected? If the latter, why did you expect that exact distance; have you adjusted this value somewhere?

Comment: Too much compare to normal frame movement. I don't even know how can I adjust this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your custom UITableViewCell use layoutSubviews and willTransitionToState. 
In your .h file add  int state;
In your .m cell add

```
    - (void)willTransitionToState:(UITableViewCellStateMask)aState
    {
        [super willTransitionToState:aState];
        state = aState;
    }
```

Also add this:

```
    - (void)layoutSubviews
    {
     [super layoutSubviews];
     self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                     self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                     self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                     self.contentView.frame.size.height);
           if (self.editing )
            {
             switch (state) {
             case 2:
            // swipe action -> here you play with how much your content will move
             self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(90,
                                                  self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                                  self.contentView.frame.size.width-90,
                                                  self.contentView.frame.size.height);
            break;
              }
            } else {
            NSLog(@"subview not in edit %i",state);
            self.contentView.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                         self.contentView.frame.origin.y,
                                         self.contentView.frame.size.width,
                                         self.contentView.frame.size.height);
             [self setNeedsDisplay];
   }
}
```

This should be enough to customize indent.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happen due to layout of cell is not getting called use custom cell and set frames in layoutSubviews this will fix your problem